# How to read data from Realm

Tags: android, realm

I develop my login application using Realm.
I write in Realm my token in line 'Config myConfig = mRealm.createObject(Config.class)'. Afterwards reading from Realm gives no result likewise Realm has no entries.
I do check in this piece of code that I tagged as '//check - why no users here'.
And User.size() equals to zero.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Realm mRealm;
    private Realm mRealmInstance;

    Button btnLogin;

    public void onLogin() {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
        rp.add("email", "name@example.com");
        rp.add("password", "159753");

        RequestHandle post = client.post("https://example.com/api/v1/auth", rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // Root JSON in response is an dictionary i.e { "data : [ ... ] }
                // Handle resulting parsed JSON response here
                try {
                    String tokenString = response.getString("token");

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    Config myConfig = mRealm.createObject(Config.class);
                    myConfig.name = "token";
                    myConfig.tokenValue = tokenString;
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }
        });

        //check - why no users here
        TextView tvHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
        try {
            RealmResults User = mRealmInstance.where(Config.class).equalTo("name", "token").findAllAsync();
            if (User.size() > 0) {

                String nameOfUser = User.get(0).toString();
                tvHello.setText(nameOfUser);

            } else if (User.size() == 0) {
                Log.e("query","query size is "+User.size());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        //end of test block
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing an asynchronous network call before accessing your data. The network call has not completed yet, therefore your data is empty. Put your data access code in the `onSuccess()` callback.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

...

public void onLogin() {

    ...

    RequestHandle post = client.post(
        "https://example.com/api/v1/auth", 
        rp, 
        new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(
            int statusCode, 
            Header[] headers, 
            JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String tokenString = response.getString("token");

                mRealm.beginTransaction();
                Config myConfig = mRealm.createObject(Config.class);
                myConfig.name = "token";
                myConfig.tokenValue = tokenString;
                mRealm.commitTransaction();

                populateData();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(
            int statusCode,
            Header[] headers, 
            String res, 
            Throwable t) {
            // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
        }
    });
}

private void populateData() {
    TextView tvHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
    try {
        RealmResults User = 
            mRealmInstance.where(Config.class).equalTo("name", "token").findAll();
        if (User.size() > 0) {

            String nameOfUser = User.get(0).toString();
            tvHello.setText(nameOfUser);

        } else if (User.size() == 0) {
            Log.e("query","query size is "+User.size());
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Also note that you should use `findAll()` instead of `findAllAsync()`. Read the documentation for more information on the difference: https://realm.io/blog/realm-java-0-84-0/

Answer (score 1):

This is because `client.post(...` will be executed in another thread. Only after that task is completed `onSuccess()`will be executed in the UI thread. The code after `//check - why no users here` is executed before or while `onSuccess()` is executing. That is why `User.size()` equals to zero. Modify your code to get it working

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Realm mRealm;
    private Realm mRealmInstance;
    private TextView tvHello;

    Button btnLogin;

    public void onLogin() {

        tvHello = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
        rp.add("email", "name@example.com");
        rp.add("password", "159753");

        RequestHandle post = client.post("https://example.com/api/v1/auth", rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // Root JSON in response is an dictionary i.e { "data : [ ... ] }
                // Handle resulting parsed JSON response here
                try {
                    String tokenString = response.getString("token");

                    mRealm.beginTransaction();
                    Config myConfig = mRealm.createObject(Config.class);
                    myConfig.name = "token";
                    myConfig.tokenValue = tokenString;
                    mRealm.commitTransaction();

                    RealmResults User = mRealmInstance.where(Config.class).equalTo("name", "token").findAllAsync();
                    if (User.size() > 0) {

                        String nameOfUser = User.get(0).toString();
                        tvHello.setText(nameOfUser);

                    } else if (User.size() == 0) {
                        Log.e("query", "query size is " + User.size());
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Great! If this answer helped to solve your issue please upvote and mark this as the answer as this will be helpful for others with similar issue. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 1):

To receive notifications when the Realm was written to from a background thread, you should use a RealmChangeListener (and keep the RealmResults as a field).

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Realm realm;

    Button btnLogin;

    private RealmResults<Config> userResults;
    private RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Config>> changeListener = new RealmChangeListener<RealmResults<Config>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChange(RealmResults<Config> element) {
            TextView tvHello = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvHello);
            try {
                if (element.size() > 0) {        
                    String nameOfUser = element.get(0).toString();
                    tvHello.setText(nameOfUser);        
                } else if (element.size() == 0) {
                    Log.e("query","query size is "+element.size());
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(..);
        realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
        userResults = realm.where(Config.class).equalTo("name", "token").findAllAsync();
        userResults.addChangeListener(changeListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        userResults.removeAllChangeListeners();
        userResults = null;
        realm.close();
        realm = null;
    }

    public void onLogin() {

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

        RequestParams rp = new RequestParams();
        rp.add("email", "name@example.com");
        rp.add("password", "159753");

        RequestHandle post = client.post("https://example.com/api/v1/auth", rp, new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {
                // Root JSON in response is an dictionary i.e { "data : [ ... ] }
                // Handle resulting parsed JSON response here
                try {
                    String tokenString = response.getString("token");

                    try(Realm r = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                        r.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                Config myConfig = realm.createObject(Config.class);
                                myConfig.name = "token";
                                myConfig.tokenValue = tokenString;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String res, Throwable t) {
                // called when response HTTP status is "4XX" (eg. 401, 403, 404)
            }
        });

        //end of test block
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, it is useful